RTE wraps content with &#8203; when <video> element is present
In Sitecore 10.3 Update 0, when I add a <video> element in the RTE, Sitecore adds &#8203; (a zero-width space HTML entity) at the beginning and end of the content in the RTE.
Input:
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some More text </p>
<p><video controls="true" width="560" height="315">
<source src="/mediafiles/My%20Video%20Name%Is,%20This%202024-03-28.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video></p>
<p>Some footer text</p>

After accepting and reopening the HTML editor, you can see the problematic values added at the beginning and end of the content:

If I remove the &#8203; values and accept, it just gets added back again.
The issue can also be replicated by entering only <video></video> but the example above is better because you can see &#8203; wrapping the entire raw value rather than just around the <video> element.
The expectation is that shouldn't happen. Is this a bug? I'm not finding any information about this.

RichText is for rich text - its for styled text content. Its not really there to add html elements. If you want to do that, you should use a multiline text or just create a video component. IIRC - the RTE will try and strip out any "code" that it finds.

Sitecore Support was able to reproduce this issue on a clean install. They registered this as a bug in the current version of Sitecore (10.3.x) and provided a reference number 464122.
A workaround fix was also provided which involves overriding the Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Dialogs.EditHtml.EditHtmlPage class from Sitecore.Client.dll and modifying RTEFixes.js in the <website>\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor folder. Specifically, modifying the fixVideoHtml() function.

This is being set from the EditHtml control through the codebeside below located at the  'sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Dialogs\EditHtml' path.
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Dialogs.EditHtml.EditHtmlPage,Sitecore.Client


Its a zero width space character intended for line break control, that is added for the HTML validation made in the browser. You can find more reference on this entity below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203
Hope this helps!!
